# Почему координаты смещаются у фигуры canvas rotate

Tags: canvas

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
if(canvas.getContext){
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
ctx.fillRect(90,50,30,20);

}}
```

прямоугольник здорово откланяется от координат вначале

Comment: Какие у него координаты центра вращения?

Comment: думал что 90,50 ,но 0,0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Канва поворачивается, вокруг начала координат, точки (0,0) - это левый верхний угол канвы.

Я в таких случаях действую следующим образом:

1. Сохраняю состояние контекста
2. Перемещаю канву в центр фигуры
3. Поворачиваю канву
4. Рисую фигуру так, как будто она расположена вокруг точки (0.0)
5. Восстанавливаю состояние контекста

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var rects = Array(12).fill(0).map((e,i) => [
  50+Math.random()*500, 
  25+Math.random()*125,
  Math.random()*40+10,
  Math.random()*20+5,
  i*30
]);

requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(t){
  ctx.clearRect(-1111, -1111, 2222, 2222);
  rects.forEach((r, i) => {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle=`hsl(${r[4]+t/100},55%,55%)`;
    ctx.translate(r[0]+r[2]/2, r[1]+r[3]/2);
    ctx.rotate(t/1000*(i+1));
    ctx.fillRect(-r[2]/2, -r[3]/2, r[2], r[3]);
    ctx.restore();
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=600 height=175>
```

Comment: Хорошо,что так.

Comment: @gdhury я не понял о чем Вы :)